# Rspec Rails: getting couldn't find Post with id / No Route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm testing `create` action with rspec, It's giving me:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
>          Couldn't find Post with 'id'=:post_id

not sure, why this is happening, any suggestion?

**spec:**

```
describe CommentsController  do
  it "#create" do
    post1 = create(:post)
    post :create, comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: post1.id)
    p Comment.count
  end
end
```

**create action:**

```
 def create
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.json { render json: @comment }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Before action:**

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_post, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
```

**Routes:**

```
  post_comments GET /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)        comments#index
                POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
  post_comment  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) comments#destroy
```

Comment: Please share some stacktrace and your `find_post` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
describe CommentsController  do
  it "#create" do
    post1 = create(:post)
    post :create, { post_id: post1.id, comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: post1.id) }
    p Comment.count
  end
end
```

I guess the problem is you are not sending `post_id` in the params.

Comment: the test pass, but `Comment.count` is `0` and should be `1`

Comment: There must be some validation failing for Comment.

Comment: Replace this `if @comment.save` with `if @comment.save!` inside your controller and you will see.

Comment: Another thing, the test will pass because you are not checking anything inside the `it` block. You should do `expect(Comment.count).to eq 1` after `post :create, ...` statement.

Comment: `comment: attributes_for(:comment, post_id: post1.id)` here i think no need to pass `post_id` again.

Comment: Re: comment not being saved, please share `comment_params` method too.

Comment: `params.require(:comment).permit(:content)` thats my comment_params still getting 0

Comment: Did you try `save!` instead of `save`? That will raise exception if comment not valid.

Comment: nope, `expect(Comment.count).to eq 1` doesn't pass. tried `save!` but it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: That means it is not going to your `create` action. You should check inside `find_post` if the post is found.

Comment: i finally, figured why it's not going through `create` action. devise wants to authenticate the user first. i had this `before_action :authenticate_user!` thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not passing `post_id` properly. pass like this and debug in `find_post` method, how params coming there.

```
describe CommentsController  do
  it "#create" do
    post1 = create(:post)
    post :create, { post_id: post1.id, comment: { comment_attributes_here } }
    p Comment.count
  end
end
```

Comment: Same as my answer.